# Update one column to value of another in Rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration, timestamp

I have a table in a Rails app with hundreds of thousands of records, and they only have a `created_at` timestamp. I'm adding the ability to edit these records, so I want to add an `updated_at` timestamp to the table. In my migration to add the column, I want to update all rows to have the new `updated_at` match the old `created_at`, since that's the default for newly created rows in Rails. I could do a `find(:all)` and iterate through the records, but that would take hours because of the size of the table. What I really want to do is:

```sql
UPDATE table_name SET updated_at = created_at;
```

Is there a nicer way to do that in a Rails migration using ActiveRecord rather than executing raw SQL?

Answer (score 162, accepted):

I would create a migration

```
rails g migration set_updated_at_values
```

and inside it write something like:

```
class SetUpdatedAt < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    Yourmodel.update_all("updated_at=created_at")
  end

  def self.down
  end
end
```

This way you achieve two things

- this is a repeatable process, with each possible deploy (where needed) it is executed
- this is efficient. I can't think of a more rubyesque solution (that is as efficient).

Note: you could also run raw sql inside a migration, if the query gets too hard to write using activerecord. Just write the following:

```
Yourmodel.connection.execute("update your_models set ... <complicated query> ...")
```

Comment: +1 - I recently had to do exactly this and used SQL over an ActiveRecord. It's as fast as it can get.

Comment: `Yourmodel.update_all 'update_at=created_at'` is nicer, no? It works on a scope too.

Comment: According to the [Rails guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#using-the-up-down-methods): *"the database schema should be unchanged if you do an `up` followed by a `down`"*. So consider `def change` only instead.

Comment: @EliadL a few remarks: 1) we are not changing the schema, just the contents  of the database. And 2) at the time this answer was written, the `change` method did not yet exist, but in this case I still prefer to use explicit `up` and `down` to be more explicit (if you would want to control what the `down` should do).

Comment: I think your down method should put things back to how they were before the up method was run, whether it's structure or content of the database. If you can't figure out how to do that then leave the down method out and make it not able to roll back

Comment: Good suggestion. In my own case I generally add a (generic) column to all tables, named `migration_id` which I can set during a migration, to be able to rollback the migration later if ever needed.

Comment: Best practice says do NOT use Models within migrations. Contrary to everywhere else in a Rails app, it's better to use raw SQL here. Three years from now, `Yourmodel` might not exist in the code, perhaps renamed to `Usermodel` or whatever two years in. At that point, a three-year-old migration will fail, and a new hire will have to become an archeologist to fix it. However, at the point this migration runs, the `yourmodels` table *will* exist, regardless of the state of the application code in this-is-the-future code.

Comment: I understand that, but why not use the power of rails? It is easily fixed by locally defining the `YourModel` class (no code needed). I have used this in the rare case where we had a big data model redesign which you do in separate steps locally, but on a production machine there will be the mismatch you mentioned, between the code and db-model. But running a 3yo migration? I always use `rake db:setup` on a dev machine, which uses the schema instead of the migrations to build the db-model (and leave the migrations as documentation).

Answer (score 21):

You can use [update_all](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all) which works very similar to raw SQL. That's all options you have.

BTW personally I do not pay that much attention to migrations. Sometimes raw SQL is really best solution. Generally migrations code isn't reused. This is one time action so I don't bother about code purity.

Comment: That depends on your deployment needs. I really like to use migrations, because they allow to repeatable deploy on existing platforms and get the same result. We have several stages of deploying: dev, test, qa/acceptance, a proof of concept platform (for testing clients), a production platform: we need to be able to migrate existing data to the newly deployed version without a fault. Adding a column and making sure the data is ok is in our case NOT a one time action.

Comment: I write about using `update_all` inside migration file :-) You can also execute raw SQL inside migration file. However `update_all` is a little bit more elegant. Both will perform exactly the same.

Comment: It's usually a smart idea to declare the model in the migration, since this will prevent problems if the original model is redefined later on. Just found this article which explains everything quite nicely: http://complicated-simplicity.com/2010/05/using-models-in-rails-migrations/

Comment: With `update_all` i have no idea how to set a value of column to that of another, as the OP requested. Please demonstrate.

Answer (score 20):

As gregdan wrote, you can use `update_all`. You can do something like this:

```
Model.where(...).update_all('updated_at = created_at')
```

The first portion is your typical set of conditions. The last portion says how to make the assignments. This will yield an `UPDATE` statement, at least in Rails 4.

Comment: This in 4.2 generates `SET'posts'.'email' = 'options'`, the options is a literal string

Comment: Confirming this tip doesn't work for me too. Unsure that it's completely wrong solution. Don't donwvote @martin answer

Comment: Here is the output from the Rails console: `User.update_all('updated_at = created_at')` `SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "users" SET updated_at = created_at`

Answer (score 5):

You can directly run following command to your `rails console`
`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COL2 = COL1")`

For example: I want to update sku of my items table with remote_id of items tables. the command will be as following:
`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("UPDATE items SET sku = remote_id")`

Comment: Actually this is far most "history" secure way, because in future (when some will run migrations, the model `Yourmodel` can be already deleted. Try to avoid using models in migrations.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use application models in migrations unless you redefine them inside migration. If you use application model tahat you later change or delete your migration might fail.

Of course you can also use full power of SQL inside migrations.

Read https://makandracards.com/makandra/15575-how-to-write-complex-migrations-in-rails

Answer (score 1):

You can also add updated_at column and update its values in one migration:

```
class AddUpdatedAtToTableName < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :table_name, :updated_at, :datetime

    reversible do |dir|
      dir.up do
        update "UPDATE table_name SET updated_at=created_at"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I consider this bad practice: I prefer to separate my migrations into 1) schema changes and 2) keep data changes separate. For clarity.

Answer (score 0):

This is a General way of solving, without the need for Writing Query, as queries are subjected to risk.

```
  class Demo < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
     add_column :events, :time_zone, :string
     Test.all.each do |p|
       p.update_attributes(time_zone: p.check.last.time_zone)
     end
     remove_column :sessions, :time_zone
    end
  end
```

Comment: Please explain: why are queries subjected to risk? If you are changing deployment to a different database?

Answer (score -5):

As a one time operation, I would just do it in the `rails console`. Will it really take hours? Maybe if there are millions of records…

```
records = ModelName.all; records do |r|; r.update_attributes(:updated_at => r.created_at); r.save!; end;`
```

Comment: That's essentially what I tried first, but because there are hundreds of thousands of records that need to be changed, that will take hours (days?).

Comment: When I tested it it was going at about 50 records a second on my developer machine (not a server).

Comment: Always avoid iteration if possible, avoid using 'all' which loads every record into RAM at once, and since update_attributes already does a save automatically, the additional call to save! will make the entire operation take twice as long.