# Copy one column in a database table to a different column in the same table in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

I am trying to do a migration of a column in a table in my database. I have a 'name' field and I want to migrate all the info in the name field to a 'user_name' field. What is the correct way in ruby on rails to copy the values of one column in the user table to another column in the same table?

Comment: Duplicate of [Update one column to value of another in Rails migration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224881/update-one-column-to-value-of-another-in-rails-migration)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the column

```
add_column :table, :user_name, :string
```

and then run an update script (in a db console or via `execute` in a migration file)

```
update table set user_name = name;
```

Or, if you don't want to keep the old column, you can [just rename it](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html).

```
rename_column :table, :name, :user_name
```

> **rename_column(table_name, column_name, new_column_name)**: Renames a column but keeps the type and content.

Comment: Where would you run this "update script"? Can you do it in the rails console?

Comment: @Michael, mysql console

Comment: @bertbruynooghe: it is not actually mysql-specific. Would work just as well in PG